# npmlog accessing superCtor.prototype

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

Recently, I've seen travis builds fail if they use node 0.8, like [this one here](https://travis-ci.org/polotek/libxmljs/jobs/57487309). The report reads something like this:

```
$ npm install

util.js:538
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:538:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/.nvm/v0.8.28/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:115:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/.nvm/v0.8.28/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Could it be that the [`npmlog`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmlog) module installed here is incompatible with node 0.8? Is there anything a project should do to fix this, is this a Travis bug to be reported somewhere, or has travis simply terminated support for node 0.8 even though it's [still listed](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/)?